# What is the fastest way to copy content of DVD to hard disk using Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, dvd

I have gone through some of the links Which talks about fastest way of copying files in windows using `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` and `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` . It also talks about how 
request made for read and write opeartions with `BUFFER SIZE` as `256KB and 128KB` are faster than `1Mb` .The link for that is :-
[Explanation for tiny reads (overlapped, buffered) outperforming large contiguous reads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909345/explanation-for-tiny-reads-overlapped-buffered-outperforming-large-contiguous)
I am also loking for a Similar method in linux Which allows me to copy the content of my DVD to Hard Disc in a fast Way . So I wanted to know Is there some file operation flags in Linux which would provide me the best result or Which way of Copy in Linux is the best ? My codes are all in c++.

Comment: I dont know i see a down vote by a User without any specific comment or reason for doing so ?

Comment: system( "dd if=/dev/dvd of=/path/to/img bs=16384" ) should be plenty fast

Comment: @stijn What I understand is that its a system call but can you please explain me the above line and What is the `bs` there ?

Comment: @stijn My DVD will have a Playlist which will contain some files . I want to copy say particular files from those playlist . Will it be still that efficient ?

Comment: dd (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix) or man dd) does a raw copy so no, you cannot use it for copying only a part of a dvd

Comment: Those links are for optimizing disk-to-disk copying. When copying from a DVD, reading will be the bottleneck. Writing to the hard disk will have no problems keeping up with that.

Comment: @Bo Persson What do you think would be a best way to copy in case of Linux ?

Comment: @Ritesh - I just don't think there is a problem to solve. Reading from the DVD is the bottleneck, and that will limit the speed of copying. You cannot do much about that.

Answer (score 1):

Mount your DVD, open() the files you want to copy, and use sendfile(). If you'd like to copy the full DVD, you might also try to open() the DVD's /dev entry and pass that descriptor to sendfile().

```
$ man 2 sendfile
```

"sendfile() copies  data between one file descriptor and another.  Because this copying is done within the kernel, sendfile() is more efficient than the combination of read(2) and write(2), which would require  transferring data to and from user space."