# MapViewOfFile and VirtualLock

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, windows-7, file-mapping

Will the following code load data from file into system memory so that access to the resulting pointer will never block threads?

```
auto ptr = VirtualLock(MapViewOfFile(file_map, FILE_MAP_READ, high, low, size), size); // Map file to memory and wait for DMA transfer to finish.
int val0 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(ptr)[0]; // Will not block thread?
int val1 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(ptr)[size-4]; // Will not block thread?

VirtualUnlock(ptr);
UnmapViewOfFile(ptr);
```

EDIT:

Updated after Dammons answer.

```
auto ptr = MapViewOfFile(file_map, FILE_MAP_READ, high, low, size);

#pragma optimize("", off)
char dummy;
for(int n = 0; n < size; n += 4096)
    dummy = reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr)[n];
#pragma optimize("", on)

int val0 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(ptr)[0]; // Will not block thread?
int val1 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(ptr)[size-4]; // Will not block thread?

UnmapViewOfFile(ptr);
```

Comment: Are you asking what typically happens or what is absolutely guaranteed? And by "block a thread" do you mean that disk I/O is required?

Comment: What typically happens. Yes, when disk I/O is required the thread is blocked.

Comment: This typically invokes the "Windows is not a real-time operating system" comment.  You'll need to keep it locked.  And its next to impossible to get the optimizer to not remove those statements, you must use #pragma optimize to stop it being helpful.

Comment: On the function, not inline inside the function body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file's size is less than the ridiculously small maximum working set size (or, if you have modified your working set size accordingly) then *in theory* yes. If you exceed your maximum working set size, `VirtualLock` will simply do nothing (that is, fail).

(In practice, I've seen `VirtualLock` being rather... liberal... at interpreting what it's supposed to do as opposed to what it actually does, at least under Windows XP -- might be different under more modern versions)

I've been trying similar things in the past, and I'm now simply touching all pages that I want in RAM with a simple `for` loop (reading one byte). This leaves no questions open and works, with the sole possible exception that a page *might* in theory get swapped out again after touched. In practice, this never happens (unless the machine is really really low on RAM, and then it's ok to happen).

Comment: Updated my question, do you mean something like that? How do I keep the compiler from optimizing away the loop?

Comment: How do I get the proper "page size"/stride in windows?

Comment: One way of keeping the compiler from optimizing the loop away is summing up a value and then (after the loop) assigning the sum to a `volatile` variable. This is usually faster than making `dummy` itself `volatile` (which nevertheless is an option too). About the proper stride, the correct way of doing it is to use `dwPageSize` from `GetSystemInfo`. However, just assuming a page size of 4096 is "OK", because it works on all systems, the worst thing to happen is that you touch a few extra memory locations unnecessarily on architectures having larger page sizes.

Comment: According to my experience, you can in fact, although this is "incorrect", only touch every 8th page (i.e. use an 64k stride), because Windows will at least prefetch 8 pages at a time under XP (and more on later versions). Although it doesn't create the pages at that time, it still pulls them into the buffers. This means you _will_ get a fault when first accessing the odd pages (not when accessing the even ones) but this is a very low impact, not actually _loading_ anything. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5909345/572743) under "Sidenote".