# Overlapped IO or file mapping?

Tags: winapi, file-io, overlapped-io, file-mapping

In a Windows application I have a class which wraps up a filename and a buffer.  You construct it with a filename and you can query the object to see if the buffer is filled yet, returning nullptr if not and the buffer addres if so.  When the object falls out of scope, the buffer is released:

```
class file_buffer
{
public:
    file_buffer(const std::string& file_name);
    ~file_buffer();
    void* buffer();

private:
    ...
}
```

I want to put the data into memory asynchronously, and as far as I see it I have two choices: either create a buffer and use overlapped IO through ReadFileEx, or use MapViewOfFile and touch the address on another thread.

At the moment I'm using ReadFileEx which presents some problems, as requests greater than about 16MB are prone to failure: I can try splitting up the request but then I get synchronisation issues, and if the object falls out of scope before the IO is complete I have buffer-cleanup issues.  Also, if multiple instances of the class are created in quick succession things get very fiddly.

Mapping and touching the data on another thread would seem to be considerably easier since I won't have the upper limit issues: also if the client absolutely has to have the data right now, they can simply dereference the address, let the OS worry about page faults and take the blocking hit.

This application needs to support single core machines, so my question is: will page faults on another software thread be any more expensive than overlapped IO on the current thread?  Will they stall the process?  Does overlapped IO stall the process in the same way or is there some OS magic I don't understand?  Are page faults carried out using overlapped IO anyway?

I've had a good read of these topics:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365199(v=vs.85).aspx (IO Concepts in File Management)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556(v=vs.85).aspx (File mapping)
but I can't seem to infer how to make a performance tradeoff.

Comment: Woo hoo!  I've got the tumbleweed badge.  Maybe I should add the C++ tag...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will definitively want to go with memory-mapped files. Overlapped IO (with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`) has been advocated as "the fastest way to get data into RAM" by some people for years, but this is only true in very contrieved cases with very specific conditions. In the normal, average case, turning off the buffer cache is a serious anti-optimization.

Now, overlapped IO *without* `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`has all the quirks of overlapped IO, and is about 50% slower (for a reason I still cannot understand).

I've done some rather extensive benchmarking [a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5909345/572743). The bottom line is: Memory mapped files are faster, better, less surprising.

Overlapped IO uses more CPU, is much slower when using the buffer cache, asynchronous reverts to synchronous under some well-documented and some undocumented conditions (e.g. encryption, compression, and... pure chance? request size? number of requests?), stalling your application at unpredictable times.
Submitting requests can sometimes take "funny" amounts of time, and `CancelIO` sometimes doesn't cancel anything but waits for completion. Processes with outstanding requests are unkillable. Managing buffers with outstanding overlapped writes is non-trivial extra work.

File mapping just works. Fullstop. And it works nicely. No surprises, no funny stuff. Touching every page has very little overhead and delivers as fast as the disk is able to deliver, and it takes advantage of the buffer cache. Your concern about a single-core CPU is no problem. If the touch-thread faults, it blocks, and as always when a thread blocks, another thread gets CPU time instead.

I'm even using file mapping for *writing* now, whenever I have more than a few bytes to write. This is somewhat non-trivial (have to manually grow/preallocate files and mappings, and truncate to actual length when closing), but with some helper classes it's entirely doable. Write 500 MiB of data, and it takes "zero time" (you basically do a `memcpy`, the actual write happens in the background, any time later, even after your program has finished). It's stunning how well this works, even if you know that it's the natural thing for an operating system to do.
Of course you had better not have a power failure before the OS has written out all pages, but that's true for any kind of writing. What's not on the disk yet *is not on the disk* -- there's really not much more to say to it than that. If you must be sure about that, you have to wait for a disk sync to complete, and even then you can't be sure the lights aren't going out *while you wait for the sync*. That's life.

Answer (score 4):

I don't claim to understand this better than you, as it seem you made some inventigation. And to be totally sure you will need to experiment. But this is my understanding of the issues, in reverse order:

1. File mapping and overlapped IO in Windows are different implentations and none of them rely on the other *under the hood*. But both use the asynchronous block device layer. As I imagine it, in the kernel every IO is actually asynchronous, but some user operations wait for it to finish and so they create the illusion of synchronicity.
2. From point 1, if a thread does IO, other threads from the same process will *not* stall. That, unless the system resources are scarce or these other threads do IO themselves and face some kind of contention. This will be true no matter the kind of IO the first thread does: blocking, non-blocking, overlapped, memory-mapped.
3. In memory-mapped files, the data is read at least one page at a time, probably more because of the read-ahead, but you cannot be sure about that. So the probing thread will have to touch the mapped memory at least one on every page. That will be something like probe/block-probe-probe-probe-probe/block-probe... That might be a bit less efficient than a big overlapped read of several MB. Or maybe the kernel programmers were smart and it is even more efficient. You will have to make a little profiling... Hey, you could even go without the probing thread and see what happens.
4. Cancelling overlapping operations is a PITA, so my recommendation will be to go with the memory-mapped files. That is way easier to set up and you get extra functionality:

   1. the memory is usable even before it is fully in memory
   2. the memory can/will be shared by several instances of the process
   3. if the memory is in the cache, it will be ready instantaneously instead of just quickly.
   4. if the data is read-only, you can protect the memory from writing, catching bugs.

Comment: Thanks for your input; it matches my take on the situation.  I would prefer the memory mapping approach, but I have debugged, tested code and selling the replacement requires a performance improvement.

Comment: @hatcat: You can also trying to use `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` when opening the file, if you are not already using it. It may improve the performance of both overlapped and mmaped IO.